# How to load modules from gitlab subgroup?

Tags: go

I wrote a program and want to encapsulate some logic.

So I did new module and pull it in my git. Link for git looks like
**gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj**
but when I tried to get it with go get, I got error

```
fatal: «https://xxx.ru:@gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup.git/» unreachable: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Go tried to load subgroup instead project.

I made folder gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/ in $GOPATH/src/ and clone my project.

And now it wrote

```
could not import gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj (no required module provides package "gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj")
```

So, if I understand correctly, in Golang 1.16 I can't just put my project in the correct directory and I can't use local packages.

How to fix loading from my GitLab and load it with ssh?

Thank you.

UDP go.mod in my proj.

```
module gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj

go 1.16

require (
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210608053332-aa57babbf139
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.6
)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using go modules. Did you `go mod init gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj` in your other project? What are the contents of both `go.mod` files?

Comment: yes, I did. updated question.

Comment: I found this article. Can I do like this, without loading proj as module? https://golangbyexample.com/nested-packages-golang/

Comment: I mean - you can certainly nest packages in the same repository. For example the [go stdlib](https://golang.org/pkg/) has many packages in the same repository. I thought you **wanted** the package to be in a different repo/module though.

Comment: No, I want just encapsulate some logic. But I can't understand how to import this package. because my MainProj in GitLab. If I want to import it i need to write import "gitlab.xxx.ru/group/MainProj/proj". And golang will try to download MainProj from GitLab. I cant understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: Well, in the case where you want a local subpackage, let's say your main package is "example.com/hello". All you would have to do is create a folder called "proj". Make sure you have at least one file in `/proj` with `package proj` (pretty standard to call it proj.go). Then use it from `/hello` with `import "example.com/hello/proj"`. For example, [these imports in godoc are importing from the same tools repo](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/godoc/main.go#L41).

Comment: I created test project. I called it "hello". In go.mod "module hello". I have main.go with package main and subdir with package "testsub". When I tried to import and use package hello/testsub compiler gives me error "package hello/testsub is not in GOROOT". As I read, modules shouldn't be in GOPATH or GOROOT. What I missed?

Answer (score 12):

You may be hitting the intended behaviour from Gitlab which will prevent go from fetching the list of subgroups while trying to compute project dependencies. Since `go get` requests are unauthenticated, existing projects not under the root group are invisible and cannot be found.

To overcome this limitation, which Gitlab has yet to provide a solution, you can use one of the following two approaches:

- Have the project located at the root and not in a subgroup (not always possible)
- Leverage the `.git` extension as well as the replace directive in the project which imports your module (see below)

Go is able to fetch the project living under a subgroup if it knows the version control qualifier (.git). To indicate this, make sure you import the project using the following format `gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj.git`

While this alone works, it would force you to have all those `.git` in your imports. To overcome this, you also need a `replace` directive in your `go.mod` so you can use the original import path.

In the end, the project which imports your module should have a `go.mod` that look like this:

```golang
require(
 gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj v1.7.0
)

replace(
 gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj => gitlab.xxx.ru/group/subgroup/proj.git v1.7.0
)
```